# How to update old GD library version in PHP?

Tags: php, gd

I noticed that the version of the GD library pre-installed in PHP 8 is very old.
I used this function `gd_info()` to check the version of the GD library and this is the output:

```
[GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
```

This version was released in 2013! Is it possible to update it to the latest version? If so, how to do it?

Comment: 2.3.3 was released in Sept 2021. Don't know what your setup is (local, server, Mac, Windows etc) but yes you should be able to update/upgrade it

Comment: In answer to your edit, you need to give us more information about your setup

Comment: @AndyHolmes I have an AWS EC2 server running Amazon Linux 2 and a local server installed on Windows using XAMPP. Both servers are running the latest version of PHP and have the same version of the GD library (2.1.0)